# How can I avoid the error "The file name is longer than the system-defined maximum length" in power query?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I setup a connection in excel power query to read all the file info in a folder. But I got this error (The file name is longer than the system-defined maximum length):

[image]

There are more than 100k files in this folder. I tried to replace the error and filter out this path but none of them worked. Is there way I can avoid it? It's ok to leave the error null or not reading it at all. I need the majority of file info in this folder.

Comment: Can you move the folder with the files to a different place in the filesystem where the resulting filenames will not exceed the 259 character limits Windows still has through some APIs?

Comment: see #5 under Trim multiple file names section at https://www.windowscentral.com/how-rename-multiple-files-bulk-windows-10#rename-files-using-command-prompt

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar Problem, the starting Folder was already pretty long.
I created a new network drive and used this instead so my original path went from c:\whatever\veryLong\StillNotThere\Almost\PrettyCloseNow\xy
to "z:"
I hope this helps you too or any other people stumbling across this problem.
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWNmN.png)